# Regex to match URL - number at end of string, but also match characters at start of string

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, express, next.js

I need to match the following URL format

`/yc/leroy-jenkins-123`

So I need to match both the `/yc/` part and the `123`

I am able to match the URL when its `/leroy-jenkins-123` with the following

```
server.get(/([^-]*)$/, (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/profile'
    const queryParams = { id: req.params[0] }
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})
```

So I can match the `123` with `([^-]+)$` but how do I match the `/yc/` part too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to and capture the values from group1 and group2,

```
^(\/[^\/]+\/).*?(\d+)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2NYQVz/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Matches start of string
- `(\/[^\/]+\/)` - Matches a `/` followed by any character other than `/` one or more further followed by a `/` and captures this value in group1
- `.*?` - Allows optional matching of zero or more any characters
- `(\d+)$` - Matches one or more digits and captures it in group2 followed by end of string

Comment: Very well explained answer ++

Answer (score 1):

Just alternate with `^\/\w+\/`:

```
server.get(/([^-]+)$|^\/\w+\//, ...
```

Also note that you should probably repeat *at least one* non-dash character before the end of the string, else it can match the empty string at the end, eg, a URL of

```
/
```

and nothing else would match, because there are (at least) zero non-dash characters at the end of the string, which may well not be desirable.

Unless the group is actually being used for something, feel free to leave it off entirely:

```
server.get(/[^-]+$|^\/\w+\//, ...
```